# Как отобразить все таблицы в базе Postgres начинающиеся с символов латиницы?

Tags: postgresql

Как отобразить все таблицы в базе Postgres  начинающиеся с символов латиницы затем нижнее подчеркивание затем 9 или 12 цифр например - 'tgid_123456789'. Пробую следующий запрос:

```
select table_name  from information_schema.tables where table_schema='public'
```

Вывод

```
table_name
tgid_365982800
tgid_ban_id
tgid_tarifs
tgid_365982800_conf
tgid_948727345
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делайте запрос с регулярным выражением:

```
select table_name
from information_schema.tables
where table_name ~ '^\w+_(\d{9}|\d{12})$'
```